# Merge a SQL table with a dataframe via pyodbc

Tags: python, pandas, pyodbc

I'm trying to merge a SQL table to a dataframe object using pyodbc.

The merge will delete the rows if there are no matches in the destination (SQL) table, the problem is that it seems pyodbc apply the merge row by row, and by doing so when it reach the last row, all the rows updated or inserted before will be deleted as they don't match the key of the current row.

This doesn't work using execute_many, even with the tag fast_executemany set to True (I was hoping it would as I thought my dataframe would be merged as a whole, in bulk).

I tried to do the merge with a simple execute, and creating as many placeholders as there are cells in my dataframe, and this will work, but it's just very ugly and I'm pretty sure there is a limit of placeholders we can have in one statement.

I've made a simple code to illustrate that :

```
import pandas as pd
import pyodbc

connection = pyodbc.connect(xxxxxxx, autocommit=True)
cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.fast_executemany = True

cursor.execute("DELETE FROM [dbo].[MyTable]")

merge = """MERGE [dbo].[MyTable] TARGET USING (VALUES (?,?,?,?)) as SOURCE (Country,Region,Volume,NbClients)
ON TARGET.Country = SOURCE.Country AND TARGET.Region = SOURCE.Region 
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET TARGET.Volume = SOURCE.Volume, TARGET.NbClients = SOURCE.NbClients
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN INSERT (Country,Region,Volume,NbClients) VALUES (SOURCE.Country, SOURCE.Region, SOURCE.Volume, SOURCE.NbClients) 
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE THEN DELETE;
"""    

res = pd.DataFrame([['France', 'Finistere', 19488788.334505435, 13], ['France', 'Savoie', 11282506.25, 75], ['Maroc', 'Casablanca', 12454559.801253136, 15], ['Perou', 'Quito', 13059125.212926773, 49]])
# Won't work, only the last row of the dataframe will be in the table
cursor.executemany(merge, res.values.tolist())


res = pd.DataFrame([['France', 'Vendee', 1488788.3254, 56], ['Maroc', 'Casablanca', 42454559.801253136, 36]])
# Won't work, only the last row of the dataframe will be in the table
cursor.executemany(merge, res.values.tolist())

merge_flat = """MERGE [dbo].[MyTable] TARGET USING (VALUES (?,?,?,?), (?,?,?,?)) as SOURCE (Country,Region,Volume,NbClients)
ON TARGET.Country = SOURCE.Country AND TARGET.Region = SOURCE.Region 
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET TARGET.Volume = SOURCE.Volume, TARGET.NbClients = SOURCE.NbClients
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN INSERT (Country,Region,Volume,NbClients) VALUES (SOURCE.Country, SOURCE.Region, SOURCE.Volume, SOURCE.NbClients) 
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE THEN DELETE;"""

params =  [item for sublist in res.values.tolist() for item in sublist] 
# Will work but need to have a placeholder for each cell
cursor.execute(merge_flat, *params)
```

The table is simply something like :

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MyTable](
    [Country] [varchar](30) NOT NULL,
    [Region] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [Volume] [numeric](24, 6) NULL,
    [NbClients] [numeric](24, 10) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_MyTable] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Country] ASC,
    [Region] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

So far the best solution seems to do a Delete/Insert, or maybe use a temporary table, insert my data in there and do the merge on it, but I can't believe something that should be so simple doesn't work.

Am I missing something ?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using SQL Server 2016 or newer then you can use `OPENJSON`, like so:

```py
import pandas as pd
import pyodbc

connection = pyodbc.connect(
    "DSN=mssql_199;UID=scott;PWD=tiger^5HHH", autocommit=True
)
cursor = connection.cursor()

# set up test environment
cursor.execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS [dbo].[MyTable]")
cursor.execute(
    """\
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MyTable](
    [Country] [varchar](30) NOT NULL,
    [Region] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [Volume] [numeric](24, 6) NULL,
    [NbClients] [numeric](24, 10) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_MyTable] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Country] ASC,
    [Region] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
"""
)

# example code starts here
merge = """\
MERGE [dbo].[MyTable] WITH (HOLDLOCK) as TARGET 
    USING 
        OPENJSON(?)
            WITH (
                Country varchar(30) '$.Country',
                Region varchar(50) '$.Region',
                Volume numeric(24, 6) '$.Volume',
                NbClients numeric(24, 10) '$.NbClients'
            )
    as SOURCE
    ON TARGET.Country = SOURCE.Country AND TARGET.Region = SOURCE.Region 
WHEN MATCHED THEN 
    UPDATE SET 
    TARGET.Volume = SOURCE.Volume, 
    TARGET.NbClients = SOURCE.NbClients
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN 
    INSERT (Country,Region,Volume,NbClients) 
    VALUES (SOURCE.Country, SOURCE.Region, SOURCE.Volume, SOURCE.NbClients) 
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE THEN DELETE;
"""

res = pd.DataFrame(
    [
        ("France", "Vendee", 1488788.3254, 56),
        ("Maroc", "Casablanca", 42454559.801253136, 36),
    ],
    columns=["Country", "Region", "Volume", "NbClients"],
)

cursor.execute(merge, res.to_json(orient="records"))

# check results
print(cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM MyTable").fetchall())
"""
[
  ('France', 'Vendee', Decimal('1488788.325400'), Decimal('56.0000000000')),
  ('Maroc', 'Casablanca', Decimal('42454559.801253'), Decimal('36.0000000000'))
]
"""
```

Comment: Thank you so much this seems to work !

Do you know what are the limitations in term of size for the JSON parameter ?

Comment: I'm not aware of any arbitrary limit, but if you will be dealing with hundreds of megabytes of data you might consider using `bcp` to upload the DataFrame to a scratch table on the server and then MERGE from that.